# How to merge two tables with having same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
select *
INTO [dbo].[aTable]
from dbo.bt btg left join dbo.btt bta on btg.specialty = bta.specialty 
order by 1, 6
```

I am getting the following error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Specialty' in table 'aTable' is specified more than once.

Columns for `bt` table:

```
Location
Specialty
Provider
```

Column for `btt` table:

```
Specialty
Topic
```

I am trying to get Location, Specialty, Provider, and (join all topics for the specialty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the "Select *", which will select all fields in your result set.  Try specifying the specific fields that you want to insert.

For instance:

```
SELECT Location, btg.Specialty, Provider, Topic
INTO INTO [dbo].[aTable]
from dbo.bt btg left join dbo.btt bta on btg.specialty = bta.specialty 
order by 1, 6
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I +1 and ACCEPTED as you were the first to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Alias name is all you need** to mention to avoid conflict when you join two tables with same column names.

```
SELECT btg.Location, btg.Specialty, btg.Provider,btg.Topic
INTO INTO [dbo].[aTable]
from dbo.bt btg join dbo.btt bta on btg.specialty = bta.specialty 
order by 1, 6
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. +1 for the helpful response as this also works.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
select btg.*, topic
INTO [dbo].[aTable]
from dbo.bt btg left join dbo.btt bta on btg.specialty = bta.specialty
```